# How to scan QR Code on Black on Black scheme?

Tags: ios, swift, qr-code, vision

I want to scan QR Code on black on black scheme i.e. QR code is on black background and QR code is also black and Created with doted points.
I have tried to scan this type of QR (with black on black schemes QR) using **Vision Framework** with **AVFoundation**, and also tried with ISO by making it lower and higher but it didn't worked.

Please suggest any ideas, How could i achieve the results?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Vision

class qrVC: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    
    var captureSession: AVCaptureSession!
    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectMono")
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        captureSession.startRunning()
        
        guard let videoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else { return }
        let videoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput
        
        do {
            videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)
        } catch {
            return
        }
        
        if (captureSession.canAddInput(videoInput)) {
            captureSession.addInput(videoInput)
        } else {
            return
        }
        
        let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "videoQueue"))
        captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput)
        videoOutput.connection(with: .video)?.videoOrientation = .portrait
        
        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        previewLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
        previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        
        
    }
    
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        guard let pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return }
        let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, orientation: .up, options: [:])
        guard let filteredPixelBuffer = applyFilter(to: pixelBuffer) else { return }
        
        let previewImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: filteredPixelBuffer)
        let context = CIContext()
        guard let previewCGImage = context.createCGImage(previewImage, from: previewImage.extent) else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.previewLayer.contents = previewCGImage
        }
        
        
        do {
            try imageRequestHandler.perform([detectQRCodeRequest])
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    // ----- detectQRCodeRequest -----
    lazy var detectQRCodeRequest: VNDetectBarcodesRequest = {
        let detectBarcodeRequest = VNDetectBarcodesRequest(completionHandler: { request, error in
            if let results = request.results {
                if let result = results.first as? VNBarcodeObservation {
                    if let payload = result.payloadStringValue {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            // Handle the decoded payload string value here
                            print(payload)
                            
                            
                            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: payload, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
                            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
                            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        detectBarcodeRequest.symbologies = [.qr, .ean8, .ean13, .pdf417, .aztec, .code39, .code93, .code128,  .itf14, .dataMatrix]
        return detectBarcodeRequest
    }()
    

    func applyFilter(to pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer) -> CVPixelBuffer? {
        // Convert pixel buffer to CIImage
        let image = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
        
        // Apply filter to CIImage
        filter?.setValue(image, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        guard let outputImage = filter?.outputImage else { return nil }
        
        // Render filtered CIImage to CVPixelBuffer
        var outputPixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?
        CVPixelBufferCreate(nil, Int(outputImage.extent.width), Int(outputImage.extent.height), kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, nil, &outputPixelBuffer)
        let context = CIContext()
        context.render(outputImage, to: outputPixelBuffer!)
        
        return outputPixelBuffer
    }
}
```

Example Photos

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAmiU.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJG2m.jpg)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaMBt.jpg)

Comment: Try with a [colour invert filter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cifilter/3228292-colorinvertfilter)

Comment: Try with a [colourinvertfilter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cifilter/3228292-colorinvertfilter) but its not working.

Comment: You are probably going to struggle. The contrast is too low

Comment: That will be difficult because that's not really a valid QR code. The detection is typically looking for the fixed patterns in the corners and it detects them by looking for straight lines (rectangles). Not only you have no contrast between white and black but the lines themselves have interruptions.